# Can't get LineChartBuilder to compile

Tags: javafx-2

I'm creating an application that uses JavaFX 2.2 and have run into a problem. I'm trying to use a `LineChartBuilder`, like so:

```
LineChart<Number, Number> chart = LineChartBuilder.<Number, Number>
        create()
        .XAxis(NumberAxisBuilder.create().label("X axis").build())
        .YAxis(NumberAxisBuilder.create().label("Y axis").build())
        .build();
```

However, I'm getting the following compiler errors:

```
java: reference to create is ambiguous, both method create() in 
javafx.scene.layout.RegionBuilder and method <X,Y>create() in 
javafx.scene.chart.LineChartBuilder match
```

and

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method XAxis(javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis)
  location: class javafx.scene.layout.RegionBuilder<capture#1 of ?>
```

I know the first error means `LineChartBuilder` descends from `RegionBuilder` and both define a `create()` method, and the second means it's assuming the method comes from `RegionBuilder` and therefore cannot find the `XAxis` method. I've even tried casting it,

```
LineChart<Number, Number> chart = 
        ((LineChartBuilder<Number, Number, ?>) 
        LineChartBuilder.<Number, Number>create())....
```

But I get the same compiler errors.

My question is, is this a mistake in `LineChartBuilder` or am I using it wrong? Maybe there's even a workaround?

Comment: I wonder if this is only supposed to be used by the FXMLLoader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are running with JavaFX 2.2 and not a JDK8 pre-release?

JDK8 will experience these issues with builders coded for JavaFX 2.2: see [RT-24272](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-24272).

Workaround is to use `new LineChart(xaxis, yaxis)`.  See also the [Oracle forum thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2471869) post on this issue.